# Insert data into relationship table (many-to-many) with Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

I made a Spring Boot application which contains some users. These users can belong to 0, one or many groups (I omitted some lines of code for a better visualisation):

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "group_user",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")}
    )
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(String name, List<Group> groups) {
        this.name = name;
        this.groups = groups;
    }
}
```

A group can contain 0, one or many users.

```
@Entity
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public Group(String name, List<User> users) {
        this.name = name;
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

I'm using MySQL, and I have created 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name varchar(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE group (
    id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE group_user (
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    group_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id),
    KEY group_id (group_id),
    CONSTRAINT group_user_ibfk_1
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id),
    CONSTRAINT group_user_ibfk_2
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES group (id)
);
```

I managed to link an user to a group by creating this new User, passing to its constructor a group, and calling my userDao.save() method:

```
userDao.save(new User(name, groups));
```

Now I want to edit my created user and make him belong to another group.
How can I do this without creating a new user?

For example, I have this user, who is in no group:

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES(1, 'Jordan');
```

And these groups:

```
INSERT INTO group VALUES(1, 'Group 1');
INSERT INTO group VALUES(2, 'Group 2');
```

Now, how can I (in Java), link my user to Group 1 and Group 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select a **group** entity from the database with the **id** of your choice. You either use the JPA **interface** for that entity with the method **findById** or create your own custom method in the interface.

When you have the entity for the **group**, you **add it** on to the **User** entity field **groups**. After that you **save** the user **entity**.

The same process goes to the other side **group** in a bi-directional relationship.

**Recommended reading:**

1. [Difference between unidirectional and bidirectional associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360795/what-is-the-difference-between-unidirectional-and-bidirectional-jpa-and-hibernat)
2. [A bidirectional association has two sides - owner side and an inverse side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280121/spring-and-or-hibernate-saving-many-to-many-relations-from-one-side-after-form/)
3. [Hibernate ManyToMany persistance tutorial](https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-many-to-many-association-example)

Answer (score -2):

## Create table like as:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE users (
    ->     id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    ->     name varchar(255), 
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE groups (
    ->     id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     name varchar(255),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE group_users (
    ->     user_id int NOT NULL,
    ->     group_id int NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id),
    ->     CONSTRAINT group_user_ibfk_1
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    ->     CONSTRAINT group_user_ibfk_2
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups(id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)
```

## Inserting dummy data into it:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO user VALUES(1, 'Jordan');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO users VALUES(1, 'Jordan');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> INSERT INTO groups VALUES(1, 'Group 1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO groups VALUES(2, 'Group 2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into group_users values(1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into group_users values(1,2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
```

## Actual Data in tables look like:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Jordan |
+----+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from groups;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Group 1 |
|  2 | Group 2 |
+----+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from group_users;
+---------+----------+
| user_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       1 |        2 |
+---------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## Data after joined the all of the tables will look like.

```
mysql> select u.id user_id, u.name user_name,g.id group_id, g.name group_name from users u, groups g, group_users gu where u.id = gu.user_id and g.id = gu.group_id;
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| user_id | user_name | group_id | group_name |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
|       1 | Jordan    |        1 | Group 1    |
|       1 | Jordan    |        2 | Group 2    |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Hope, you cleared with the design, and how it will work in your case.